# Sails.js Multiple callbacks from Model.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery()

Tags: sails.js

After upgrading Sails.js to v1.0 native SQL queries Model.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery() fires callback multiple times, so async utils is causing error (in anyway it's not good). Below is console trace:

````
WARNING: Something seems to be wrong with this function.
It is trying to signal that it has finished AGAIN, after
already resolving/rejecting once.
(silently ignoring this...)

To assist you in hunting this down, here is a stack trace:
```
    at Object.releaseConnection (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-mysql\helpers\private\connection\release-connection.js:27:9)
    at parentQueryCb (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-mysql\helpers\join.js:228:30)
    at Object.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-mysql\helpers\private\query\run-native-query.js:64:14)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1517:30
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:1155:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:845:10)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:303:7
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:954:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:814:26)
    at Query.query [as _callback] (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machinepack-mysql\lib\send-native-query.js:320:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```
Here is the original error:
```
undefined```
````

So next I get an error in async utils that 'next' callback was called multiple times:

```
app.js 'handleErrors' error: Error: Callback was already called.
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:318:36
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\api\controllers\ManagerController.js:461:44
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\api\services\TransferUtils.js:14:24
    at afterwards (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\help-send-native-query.js:112:23)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:195:18
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at parley.retry (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1088:49)
    at parley (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\parley.js:140:5)
    at Object.runFn [as releaseConnection] (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:461:23)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:193:22
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:113:18
    at Object.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\help-send-native-query.js:106:18)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1517:30
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:1155:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:845:10)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:303:7
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:954:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:814:26)
    at Query.query [as _callback] (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machinepack-mysql\lib\send-native-query.js:320:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
app.js 'handleErrors' error: Error: Callback was already called.
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:318:36
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\api\controllers\ManagerController.js:461:44
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\api\services\TransferUtils.js:14:24
    at afterwards (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\help-send-native-query.js:112:23)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:195:18
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at parley.retry (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1088:49)
    at parley (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\parley.js:140:5)
    at Object.runFn [as releaseConnection] (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:461:23)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:193:22
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\private\do-with-connection.js:113:18
    at Object.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\datastore-method-utils\help-send-native-query.js:106:18)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1517:30
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:1155:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:845:10)
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:303:7
    at C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:954:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:814:26)
    at Query.query [as _callback] (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\machinepack-mysql\lib\send-native-query.js:320:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asder\projects\warehouse\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
```

Does anyone know WTF?